# How to create a custom GridLayout

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to extend `GridLayout` class and add my own feature to it.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof (Transform))]
public class MyGrid: GridLayout
{
}
```

But how do I instantiate it since `GridLayout` is of type `Behaviour` and I can't do it using `AddComponent<MyGrid>`?

Answer (score 0):

`GridLayout` is a `Behaviour`, and a `Behaviour` is a `Component`. You can definitely use `AddComponent<MyGrid>()`.

Comment: I can't. `AddComponent asking for "MyGrid" which is not a Unity engine type.` This is what I get. And this is how I try to create it: `gameObject.AddComponent<MyGrid>();`

Comment: MyGrid became a Unity type (Component) when you inherited from GridLayout. The definition of AddComponent takes a Component: `public T AddComponent<T>() where T : Component`.

Comment: It is not a static type error. It's a runtime error.

Comment: @Humberd Oh, I see. I had to try it for myself, and you're right. It may be that GridLayout is an internal class that shouldn't be derived.

Comment: But the same thing happens if I inherit from `Component` or `Behaviour` directly.